# Remove item that was added after a XMLHttpRequest happens

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm using JavaScript with `xmlhttp` to add another line item to my form.  I'm trying to figure out how to remove a line item if a user presses the "Add Line Item" button to many times so that the form doesn't try and post empty values from the unnecessary line item.

I'm lost on how to do this, I think it has something to do with remove() but I'm not sure how to incorporate it.

Here is my JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var counter = 1;
     function addInput(div){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
          var newdiv = document.createElement(div);
          var splitResponse = xmlhttp.responseText.split( "[BRK]" );
          var firstDropdownContent = splitResponse[0];
          var secondDropdownContent = splitResponse[1];
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td><img style='background:#ffffff; float:left; ' src='../../images/spacer_icon.png'>Item " + (++counter) + "</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Description</td><td>Amount</td><td><img style='background:#ffffff; float:left; ' src='../../images/spacer_icon.png'>Tax Rate</td></tr><tr><td width='190'><select name='item[]'><option value='' selected></option>" + (firstDropdownContent) + "</select></td><td width='90'><input name='quantity[]' type='text' size='5' /></td><td width='440'><input name='description[]' type='text' size='60' /></td><td width='120'><input name='amount[]' type='text' size='6' /></td><td><select name='taxid[]'><option value='' selected></option>" + (secondDropdownContent) + "</select></td></tr></table><br />";
        }
        document.getElementById(div).appendChild(newdiv);
     }

     xmlhttp.open("GET", "invoicedropdownquery.php", false);
     xmlhttp.send();

   }
</script>
```

Here is my button

```
<input type="button" value="Add Line Item" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

And then I simply use a div to place it.

```
<div id="dynamicInput"></div>
```

Thanks in advance if you can help.  I probably would just place a gif next to each line item to delete it.

Edit: Here is the html from inside the javascript, a little easier to read.

```
<table><tr>
<td><img style='background:#ffffff; float:left; ' src='../../images/spacer_icon.png'>Item " + (++counter) + "</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Description</td>
<td>Amount</td>
<td><img style='background:#ffffff; float:left; ' src='../../images/spacer_icon.png'>Tax Rate</td></tr>
<tr><td width='190'><select name='item[]'><option value='' selected></option>" + (firstDropdownContent) + "</select></td>
<td width='90'><input name='quantity[]' type='text' size='5' /></td>
<td width='440'><input name='description[]' type='text' size='60' /></td>
<td width='120'><input name='amount[]' type='text' size='6' /></td>
<td><select name='taxid[]'><option value='' selected></option>" + (secondDropdownContent) + "</select></td></tr></table><br />
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `$.ajax`?

Comment: That JavaScript code is not using jQuery at all.

Comment: My mistake on the lingo, can you help?

Comment: @Tom do you have jQuery in the page?

Comment: No I guess not, I may have just mixed up the terminology.

Comment: There's no `jquery` tag here! why are ppl relating this to jquery? :)

Comment: @passionateCoder it was there, then was removed?

Comment: Ohhh.Didnt see that when i came here :) Sorry

Comment: Can we just start over, this entire thread is turning into a jquery argument.  I apologize for my mistake with the terminology.

Comment: @Tom : just a suggestion, please post the HTML which ur pushing into `newdiv` in a formatted way so that it'll be easy to understand where ur predicament lies. Thanks!

Comment: Why you put `document.getElementById(div).appendChild(newdiv);` outside your `if`? Try to put in inside your `if` statement.

Comment: The HTML is actually in the javascript, it goes off the screen.  I'll add it for easier viewing.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll do that last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you want to add one remove button for each row.

Basically for that it is necessary to set one dynamic id for the table added and one button which will invoke the function to remove the row passing by parameter the id of the table.

Function to remove an item of the dynamic div:

```
function removeItem(itemId){
    document.getElementById('dynamicInput').removeChild(document.getElementById(itemId));
}
```

This is your updated code without the ajax request to create rows and remove it:

```
    <script>
      var counter = 0;
      function add(div){
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          var firstDropdownContent = "first";
          var secondDropdownContent = "second";
          newdiv.id = "row"+(++counter);
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<table ><tr><td><img style='background:#ffffff; float:left;' src='../../images/spacer_icon.png'>Item " + (counter) + "</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Description</td><td>Amount</td><td><img style='background:#ffffff; float:left; ' src='../../images/spacer_icon.png'>Tax Rate</td></tr><tr><td width='190'><select name='item[]'><option value='' selected></option>" + (firstDropdownContent) + "</select></td><td width='90'><input name='quantity[]' type='text' size='5' /></td><td width='440'><input name='description[]' type='text' size='60' /></td><td width='120'><input name='amount[]' type='text' size='6' /></td><td><select name='taxid[]'><option value='' selected></option>" + (secondDropdownContent) + "</select></td><td><a href='javascript: removeItem(\"row"+counter+"\")'>Remove</a></td></tr></table>";
          document.getElementById(div).appendChild(newdiv);
        }

        function removeItem(itemId){
            document.getElementById('dynamicInput').removeChild(document.getElementById(itemId));
        }

  </script>
  <button onclick="add('dynamicInput')">Add</button>
  <div id="dynamicInput"></div>
```

Just adapt it to your current code and it should work.

Comment: Hello, when I click the button, it actually posts instead of removes the items.  The button does the same thing as my submit button.  Could you modify it to work with a link?