# How to remove xmlhttp request item

Tags: javascript, forms, xmlhttprequest

I'm using JavaScript with xmlhttp to add another line item to my form. I'm trying to figure out how to remove the line item if a user presses the "Add Line Item" button to many times so that the form doesn't try and post empty values from the unnecessary line item.

Here is my javascript code which adds the line item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
     function addInput(div){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
          var newdiv = document.createElement(div);
          var splitResponse = xmlhttp.responseText.split( "[BRK]" );
          var firstDropdownContent = splitResponse[0];
          var secondDropdownContent = splitResponse[1];
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<table id='" + (++counter) +"'>
<tr><td><img style='background:#ffffff; float:left; ' src='../../images/spacer_icon.png'>Item " + (counter) + "</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Description</td>
<td>Amount</td>
<td><img style='background:#ffffff; float:left; ' src='../../images/spacer_icon.png'>Tax Rate</td></tr>
<tr><td width='190'><select name='item[]'><option value='' selected></option>" + (firstDropdownContent) + "</select></td>
<td width='90'><input name='quantity[]' type='text' size='5' /></td>
<td width='440'><input name='description[]' type='text' size='60' /></td>
<td width='120'><input name='amount[]' type='text' size='6' /></td>
<td><select name='taxid[]'><option value='' selected></option>" + (secondDropdownContent) + "</select></td>
<td><button onclick='removeItem('row" + counter + "')'>Remove</button></td></tr></table><br />";

           document.getElementById(div).appendChild(newdiv);
          }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "invoicedropdownquery.php", false);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

Here is the javascript that removes the item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeItem(itemId){
    document.getElementById('dynamicInput').removeChild(document.getElementById(itemId));
}
</script>
```

Here is my add button

```
<input type="button" value="Add Line Item" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

Here is where the line is added.

```
<div id="dynamicInput"></div>
```

When I click the Remove button, not only does the item not get removed, the entire form posts.  I'm thinking maybe instead of a button, someone could show me how to create a clickable link instead of button.

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: When I click the Remove button, I get "SyntaxError: syntax error" followed by a POST.

Comment: I fixed a typo, now I get "TypeError: Value not an object."

Comment: Can you tell in which line exactly?

Comment: second javascript shown, this line- document.getElementById('dynamicInput').removeChild(document.getElementById(itemId));

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the line
`<button onclick='removeItem('row" + counter + "')'>Remove</button>` in your above code.

Comment: I think you might be right.  I got some help with this piece.  Should row be changed to something else?  I'm not sure how 'row' fits in.

Comment: or if you could recommend a way to redo that to a link instead.

Comment: Try it this way `<button onclick='removeItem(row" + counter + ")'>Remove</button>`.

Comment: Getting "Reference error: row2 is not defined" (It starts with row 2, row1 if a permanent fixture).  I'm thinking that "row" doesn't mean anything, should be changed to something else?  And it is still posting for some reason.

Comment: I fixed the above issue `<button onclick='removeItem(\"row" + counter + "\")'>Remove</button>`

Comment: I think it was better before, back to TypeError: Value not an object

Comment: Instead of button, I changed it to <a href='#' onclick='removeItem(row"+counter+")'>x</a> This solved the posting problem but still getting referrence error: row2 is not defined.  I think the problem is that "row" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Use the quotes with backslash to escape it. Like this `<a href='#' onclick='removeItem(\"row"+counter+"\")'>x</a>`

Comment: Didn't work.  When I use the \" escaped quotes, I get the message "Type Error: Value not an object".  When I use without the escaped quotes I get "Referrence Error: row2 is not defined"

Comment: @Tom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953316/remove-item-that-was-added-after-a-xmlhttprequest-happens/16954177?noredirect=1#comment24501634_16954177 is the answer for your problem